# All URLs show HTTP 403 in R

Tags: r, http, http-status-code-403, httr

I am running into a pretty weird issue. I was getting some HTTP 403 errors in my browser because the domains were blocked by the security system of the company. I talked with security and they opened some domains so I can access them. However even though the URLs would work in browser it still does not work in R, and that's when I found that all URLs return HTTP 403 in R and I don't know why...

```
library(httr)

http_status(GET("https://google.com/"))
$category
[1] "Client error"

$reason
[1] "Forbidden"

$message
[1] "Client error: (403) Forbidden"
```

How would I go about resolving this issue? The problem this causes is that I cannot publish any application as I run into HTTP 403 every time.

Comment: Probably need an user-agent header

Comment: That does not seem to solve the issue